# gtk problem in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, python, gtk

I installed ubuntu 12.04 64-bit I have python 2.7 with some additional packages. When I try to use simple command in python like for example `help('modules')` I have an error and python terminates.

```
    >>> help('modules')
Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  from gtk import _gtk

** (python:2729): CRITICAL **: pyg_register_boxed: assertion `boxed_type != 0' failed
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: cannot register existing type `GdkDevice'
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

In addition I cannot install matplotlib. In a long error log, apart of other stuff I have:

```
            pkg-config: looking for pygtk-2.0 gtk+-2.0

                        * Package pygtk-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config

                        * search path. Perhaps you should add the directory

                        * containing `pygtk-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH

                        * environment variable No package 'pygtk-2.0' found

                        * Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config

                        * search path. Perhaps you should add the directory

                        * containing `gtk+-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH

                        * environment variable No package 'gtk+-2.0' found

                        * You may need to install 'dev' package(s) to

                        * provide header files.

                  Gtk+: no

                        * Could not find Gtk+ headers in any of

                        * '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include',

                        * '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include', '.'
```

I tried to install gtk from synaptic but did not find exact match for gtk and installed libraries with its dependencies which I thought are the closest.
I am not sure how to test if I have it correctly installed and how to fix my python's problem

Comment: Why has this not been resolved? This bug has been ongoing since 2011. What the!? Basic python functionality broken, and the only answer provided is "don't use help()"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build and install matplotlib you'll need to install the necessary dependencies. In this particular case, it seems you are missing `python-gtk2-dev`.

As for the crash with `help('modules')` in python, it is likely that it is trying to load both the introspected bindings, as well as the old static bindings; and that will cause a crash as there are conflicting symbols in the incompatible libraries they support.

Comment: Thanks a lot it resolve matplotlib problem. 
Now when I try `help('modules')` I have different error and python freezes. 

`Warning: cannot register existing type GdkDisplayManager'from import osk`
`Warning: g_once_init_leave: assertion result != 0' failed from . import osk`
`Warning: g_type_register_static: assertion `parent_type > 0' failed from . import osk`
`Warning: g_object_new: assertion G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed  from . import osk`
Can you advise me how to resolve it?

Comment: The behavior of importing multiple versions of a library which are incompatible with each other, in the same process, is basically undefined. My advise would be to not do help('modules') as it tries to load everything which is installed in python, and thus will have undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your help. really appreciated. Will try to work out about this libraries, hopefully it will not cause any major problems.